# How do I start a regex search from the left to find the first instance

Tags: regex, notepad++

```
HJH3123|||38|323|h38|0|84  [[[MATCH]]]
HJH3123|332|44|38|323|h38|0|84
HJH3123|4431||38|323|h38|0|84
HJH3123|4431|33|38||h38|0|84
```

I only want to find || before the third | of every new line.

I've been trying to figure this out with little success.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the expected output ? Also the phrasing of your question is weird, I mean why do you specify `from the left`, you aren't using arabic language or something ...

Comment: see the fourth example line? it has a || in the middle. I don't want to search for that. Only the first instance of || from the beginning of the line.

Comment: You mean something like [this](http://regex101.com/r/oV0bM0) ?

Comment: wait one sec let me test this, i think this is it

Comment: Huh ? Lol I'm just guessing ... [guess #2](http://regex101.com/r/dG4qQ2)

Comment: it works man, thanks for your help! leave it as an answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems that the following regex does the job:

```
(?m)^[^|]*\|\|
```

**Explanation:**

- `(?m)` : set the `m` modifier which makes `^$` match start and end of line respectively
- `^` : begin of line
- `[^|]*`: match anything except `|` zero or more times
- `\|\|` : match `||`, we had to escape them since they are used in regex to express an *or statement*

[**Online demo**](http://regex101.com/r/dG4qQ2)